# How to schedule mysql event with help of liquibase?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I am using liquibase to manage db for my spring boot application. Now I want to schedule one recurring event on db. But I want to use liquibase for that. My event is as follows:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event12 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND 
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
DO 
INSERT INTO user_archieve(id,email,name,emptype,salary,time) 
SELECT * FROM user;
```

Is there any way so that I can write some code in changelog.xml and create above event on db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `<sql>` tag should do the trick.

```
    <changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
        <preConditions  onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <sqlCheck>
                <!-- if you need some checks to perform before execution -->
            </sqlCheck>
        </preConditions>
        <sql>
            CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event12 
            ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND 
            STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
            DO 
            INSERT INTO user_archieve(id,email,name,emptype,salary,time) 
            SELECT * FROM user;
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
```